# Property binding when using an array to build template

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following example where I have an array of MenuButtons which I am then using to dynamically build a menu using *ngFor:

```
buttonsDisabled: boolean = (this.someOtherService.someArray.length > 0) ? false : true;

export interface MenuButton {
  text: string;
  iconName?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

quickAccess: MenuButton[] = [
    {
      text: "Undo",
      iconName: "undo",
      disabled: this.buttonsDisabled,
    },
    {
      text: "Redo",
      iconName: "redo",
      disabled: this.buttonsDisabled,
    },
  ]
```

Then to build the menu:

```
<div id="quick-access">
  <button *ngFor="let button of quickAccess" iconName="{{button.iconName}}" [disabled]="button.disabled">{{button.text}}</button>
</div>
```

My problem is that when ***buttonsDisabled*** changes, the UI is not reflecting, I think because the value of false is being applied upon creation of the quickAccess array and then it doesn't update thereafter.

My question is, how do I make the disabled functionality work? So that everything updates correctly?

Comment: You can't use quickAccess as a JS array, but as a FormArray. Then in the HTML-Template you can loop through quickAccess.controls. In the TS you can change the disabled property of each control directly.

Answer (score 0):

Because `buttonsDisabled` is a primitive value, the value is updated once ("on init") and the array changes are not reflected as expected.

There are a lot of solutions for this issue, here are a few:

1. Declare the service as public then you can call it at the HTML

For example at the TS try something like this:

```
constructor(public someOtherService: SomeOtherService) {}
```

At the HTML call the service directly like this:

```
<div id="quick-access">
  <button *ngFor="let button of quickAccess" iconName="{{button.iconName}}" [disabled]="!(this.someOtherService.someArray.length > 0)">{{button.text}}</button>
</div>
```

2. Use behavior subject to emit changes when the array is changed. Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts)

3. Create a reference to `someArray` in the TS component **but keep in mind to remain that reference without breaking it**.

TS should be something like this:

```
someArray = this.someOtherService.someArray;
```

Then in the HTML, you can call that array, for example:

```
[disabled]="!(someArray.length > 0)"
```

Comment: My end goal is actually to be able to control the disabled states of the buttons individually i.e. with different logic, I probably didn't make that clear enough in the question.